# What's the easiest way to get mechanize for Python 3 on Debian?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mechanize

I recently wanted to port my scraper that uses `mechanize.Browser` to Python 3. I haven't found any `python3-mechanize` package or anything like that. I'm not yet familiar with Python module building with some special procedures so I don't know how would I use `2to3` there. Any suggestions?

**@edit:
I'm accepting Sibi's answer because it is currently the best. I will be pleased to award any other answer this way, if it just points to a better solution.**

Comment: Mechanize does not support python 3 yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's been no activity in the [Mechanize repository](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize) for several years. Despite the experimental Python 3 branch suggested, it has not been merged and there is no official response to the [request for support](https://github.com/jjlee/mechanize/issues/96).

If you're looking for an active project, you may wish to look elsewhere. Two similar projects compatible with Python 3 are

- [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup) - "A Python library for automating interaction with websites."
- [RoboBrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser) - "a simple, Pythonic library for browsing the web without a standalone web browser."

Both use Requests and BeautifulSoup. As of mid-2015, the latter shows slightly more activity.

Comment: Thanks! Back in 2012 I wasn't looking at project activity that much. This answer looks better to me.

Answer (score 3):

This is the experimental Python 3 branch of Mechanize: https://github.com/adevore/mechanize/tree/python3

Also see this for more details: http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~adevore/mechanize/

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get it working. Loads of errors when I just do `python3 setup.py build` and try to run the module. test.py isn't even ported to py3.

Comment: Did you try the alternative method of installation as suggested in their INSTALL.txt file?

Comment: I just did. The code doesn't seem to even have the Py3 syntax.

Comment: I just tried it. The link in the answer is broken, but in that repository, there's another branch 'python3' which also doesn't work.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs Broken link fixed.