# can mechanize be fully replaced with requests [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-2.x, mechanize-python

I found a python2 project on GitHub, and wanted to transalte it into python3. I just wondered if requests and mechanize are basically the same, and can be replaced with each other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209778/whats-the-easiest-way-to-get-mechanize-for-python-3-on-debian

Comment: @SethDifley ,I tried installing that, but it didn't work.

Comment: @SethDifley This didn't seem to work for anyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  While they have some of the same features they are definitely not the same.  Mechanize appears to have  **more** features than requests.  Mechanize has the ability to "solve" forms on a page where Requests is more for just pulling the raw HTML of a page or interacting with a web API.  For requests to gain this functionality requires another library.  You could replace Mehchanize with [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup).  In fact the creator started MechanicalSoup because Mechanize isn't ported to 3.* yet.

> I was a fond user of the Mechanize library, but unfortunately it's incompatible with Python 3 and development is inactive. MechanicalSoup provides a similar API, built on Python giants Requests (for http sessions) and BeautifulSoup (for document navigation).

Comment: Deprivaded Bulbas ,so MechanicalSoup is mechanize, but just in python3?

Comment: Yes, that is essentially true.