# What does Mechanize br.set_handle_gzip() do?

Tags: python, mechanize

Copying the setup of a mechanize browser from a tutorial I set `br.set_handle_gzip(True)`. When I scrape a site with the browser object python prints `UserWarning: gzip transfer encoding is experimental!` This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13213679/2327821) from a year ago explains that setting it to `False` will make the error message go away. Ok, obviously, but what does this setting actually control? What type of content would require this feature? Is it ok to turn it off if the page is just basic html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many web servers support compressing content before sending it to the client, to speed up transfers. They do this using gzip compression.

That setting determines whether the client will tell the server it's willing to accept gzip'd content. If it doesn't, the server will transmit the content uncompressed.

Comment: Any thoughts on the degree to which it is experimental for mechanize? Really not downloading large files.

Comment: Well, it's been in mechanize since at least 2008.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't actually print the error message in the python interpreter, only when you run the code from windows command line. So I was a little thrown when I saw the message for the first time.